# How to define TermsQuery for searching list of integer?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using the object initializer syntax, on the line that define the Terms, I am getting an error: Cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'

```
var query = new TermsQuery
{
 Field = new Field("seq"),
 Terms = new List<int> {1 ,2, 3}
};
```

This works if define using fluent DSL

```
var search = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};   

q.Terms(c => c
    .Field(p => p.seq)
    .Terms(search)
)
```

What are I doing wrong with the object initializer syntax? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `Terms = new List<object> {1 ,2, 3}`

Comment: Despite @mjwills solves the error I would check why `Terms` expects an enumerable of `object` instead of `int`. The conversion between them called boxing and unboxing and may be very costly in terms of performance.

Comment: `The conversion between them called boxing and unboxing and may be very costly in terms of performance.` For three values the performance cost will be miniscule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can attribute the failure in the first case to a fundamental point of `C#`. `int` is a value type and trying to assign a `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>` fails because generic variance is not supported for value types.  The same thing works fine if you assign a `List<string>` to the `IEnumerable<object>` reference type. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175346/5253437) answer by Jon Skeet to understand more on this. Additionally, you can look up more on the Covariance and Contravariance in generics from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). One way to get this working is performing an explicit cast on your `List<int>` type variable.

Further, for the case of fluent DSL approach, there are two overloads that are possible for the `Terms` method.

```
TermsQueryDescriptor<T> Terms<TValue>(IEnumerable<TValue> terms)
```

and

```
TermsQueryDescriptor<T> Terms<TValue>(params TValue[] terms)
```

If you take a look at the implementation of these methods from [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/QueryDsl/TermLevel/Terms/TermsQuery.cs#L62), you would see that the type `T` that is being passed in is inferred and the required casting is done internally. That is why you wouldn't face this issue in the case of fluent DSL approach.

Comment: Sai, thanks for the explanation of the issue. I have convert the list of integer into list of string and it seems to work great. Thanks again.